# Convert 22.08.2010 to 22/08/2010

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am getting the date as 22.08.2010 in to a string how can i convert it to 22/08/2010

Comment: Do you want a date, or a string as your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the variable `str` as your string.  Then:

`str = str.Replace(".", "/");`

This will work as long as you know your input string is going to be in format `XX.XX.XXXX`

Comment: Very bad solution, imo. No integrity check, etc

Comment: As long as he knows his input is 100% guaranteed to be in the form `XX.XX.XXXX` why would you spend the time verifying it?

Answer (score 10):

```
string strDate = "22.08.2010"
string result = strDate.Replace('.','/');
```

More general solution

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate,"dd.MM.yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
time.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Recommend to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Answer (score 5):

You could try using the [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method

```
string result = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "22.08.2010", 
    "dd.MM.yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

If the input format is not guaranteed to be a valid date you could try the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could either use a culture using that format or use DateTimeFormatInfo http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

all i am getting the date as 22.08.2010 in to a string how can i convert it to 22/08/2010

```
DateTime myDate=Convert.ToDateTime("22.08.2010");

String newFormat=myDate.Day.ToString()+"/"+myDate.Month.ToString()+"/"+myDate.Year.ToString();

DateTime newDateFormat=Convert.ToDateTime(newFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would create a DatimeTime object with the `DateTime.ParseExact` method and then do the `variable.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`